# Relationship between weak Lp and strong Lq topologies for q<p

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, hausdorff-spaces

Specificaly:

- Does convergence in $L^{\frac{1}{2}}$ imply weak $L^2$ convergence?
- Having a limit in $L^{\frac{1}{2}}$ topology and a limit in weak $L^2$ topology whether these are always equal? If not, what additional assumption would enable the conclusion?

Generally:

- Whether strong $L^q$ topology is finer (stronger) than a weak $L^p$ topology for some $q<p$?